# Fetching the products from metafields and looping on them in Shopify/Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to fetch the assigned products to a product in the metafields. The content type is "Product (List)" (not sure if this is the correct type but it seems so)

I tried to render them through this liquid code:

```
<section class="product-list">
  <div>
    {% for bundle_product in product.metafields.custom.bundle %}
    {% include 'single-product-card', bundle_product %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</section>
```

And here's the definition:
[image]

However, nothing is being displayed. I logged the output of `product.metafields.custom.bundle` and it returned this:

`['gid://shopify/Product/7580521365703', 'gid://shopify/Product/7510314975431']`

How should I properly loop on them?

Comment: Have you tried using the theme editor to see what those metafields expose for you to use? I am thinking they expose the whole product itself, whereas what you see there is just the GID. For example, if you tack on the .value to the metafield, and examine that, maybe you get the whole product to play with? Have you tried?

Comment: @DavidLazar Thank you for your comment, which helped me figure out that I need to use type `product_list` in the schema, then in the theme editor select dynamic > metafields `bundle`. Very weird behaviour, this should be straight forward without the need for a schema item.

Comment: At least you figured it out. Was not that big of a deal. And yes, some things in Shopify are truly poorly documented at points in time! Normal everyday stuff.

Comment: can you paste some example schema code you are using and maybe a screen shot of the editor showing off your use case. That could potentially help a lot of people out in the future.

Answer (score 0):

{% if article.metafields.custom.mentioned_products %}
{% assign mentionproduct = article.metafields.custom.mentioned_products.value %}

```
<div class="related-products" id="related-products-{{ block.id }}">
  {% for prod in mentionproduct %}
    {% if prod.available == true %}
      <a href="{{ prod.url }}" class="related-product" aria-label="{{prod.title}}" title="{{ prod.title }}">
        <img class="related-product__image" src="{{ prod.images[0] | img_url: '500x' }}" alt="{{ prod.title }}">
      </a>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

{% endif %}

Answer (score 0):

The answer above looks correct but I thought I would add a bit of explanation. The thing to do is to assign the metafield to a variable but to do that you need to use the .value property of the metafiled.

So try changing your original code this:

```
<section class="product-list">
  <div>
   {% for bundle_product in product.metafields.custom.bundle %}
   {% include 'single-product-card', bundle_product %}
   {% endfor %}
  </div>
</section>
```

To this:

```
<section class="product-list">
  <div>
   {% assign bundle_products = product.metafields.custom.bundle.value %}
   {% for bundle_product in bundle_products %}
   {% include 'single-product-card', bundle_product %}
   {% endfor %}
  </div>
</section>
```