display the Prodcut meta filed of collections to product page
I am trying to show best products based on collections . So in collections I have created a product meta field which stores the list of products . When I am retrieving the list in product page then its not showing the data .
{% assign first_collection = product.collections | first %}
 
    {% assign collection_handle = first_collection.handle %}
    <p>Collection Name: {{ collections[collection_handle].title }}</p>
 
    <div class="related-products-wrapper">
    {% assign related_products = collections[collection_handle].metafields.custom.test %}
      {{ collections[collection_handle].metafields.custom.test  }}
    {% if related_products %}
        <h3>You might also like:</h3>
        <div class="related-product-list">
            {% for related_product in related_products %}
                <a href="{{ shop.url | append: '/products/' | append: related_product.handle }}">
                    <div class="related-product">
                        <div class="related-product-image">
                            <img src="{{ related_product.featured_image | img_url: 'medium' }}" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="related-product-name">{{ related_product.title }}</div>
                        <div class="related-product-price">{{ related_product.price | money }}</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>

Here " collection_handle" is fetching the handle of collection which is attached to the product  , so want to show the products which are attached to that particular collection .
output

You need to use .value if you set metafield type as reference. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75380669/673223
